# Doctrine notation issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two classes, Multimedia and Tag which share a m:n relationship stored in a third joining table.

Owning side, Multimedia Class looks like this

```
Multimedia:
    type:   entity
    table:  multimedia

    manyToMany:                
        tags:
            targetEntity:   Tag
            inversedBy:    multimedia
            cascade:    [remove]
            orphanRemoval:  true
            joinTable:
                name: multimedia_tags
                joinColumns:
                    -
                        name: multimedia_id
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    -
                        name: tag_id
                        referencedColumnName: id

Tag:
    type: entity
    table: tags

    manyToMany:
        multimedia:
            targetEntity:   Multimedia
            mappedBy:   tags
```

Creating the relationship works fine but getting an error Notice: Undefined index: multimedia in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 471.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm not clear with .yml config, but it might need extra indentation onto lines after "manyToMany"

Comment: You got this error when you want to save into the DB righT? The problem, it's expecting a multimedia object, to know where to "link" your TAG.

Comment: @denkiryokuhatsuden, sorry the spacing was off in my question, I've rectified it as it looks in my file

Comment: @AndrásRátz I only get the error when trying to delete a Multimedia item. I've checked the multimedia_tags table where the relationships are store, the ON DELETE option says RESTRICT. When I change to CASCADE, the error goes away but item is not deleted but I get a flash message telling me there was an error. A look at the logs has no entry of the error.

Answer (score 0):

you must try to add an element to your collection in both direction.

For exemple in your entity Tag you should add this code:

```
public function addMultimedia($multimedia)
{
     if (!$this->multimedia->contains($multimedia))
     {
         $multimedia->addTag($this);
         $this->multimedia->add($multimedia);
     }
}
```

Comment: How does this affect the deleting part? Adding seems to work fine, deleting is what I have a problem with

Comment: You must then use cascade and set it to remove, and set orphanRemoval to true in your relation

Comment: so changed my multimedia entity as you directed, cleared cache..no change. I appreciate your effort to help

Comment: How do you remove your object? Look in the associative table in database and tell me if your persist works fine?

Comment: Persist works fine. I'm using the Sonata Admin Bundle delete Action to remove multimemedia which should remove associative table rows

Comment: you must remove tags from multimedia and then delete your object.

Comment: I'm still stuck at this